# Upgrading from Parallels Desktop 5 to 6 caused DNS query resolution "slowness" at Mac OS X level

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, parallels-desktop, virtualization

Anybody else feeling this/have any idea how to fix it without reinstalling Snow Leopard?
This seems very similar to problems PD used to have back in 2008 ([forum link](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?t=29675))

FWIW, my current network interfaces are:

```
$ ifconfig -l
lo0 gif0 stf0 en0 en1 fw0 vnic0 vnic1 vmnet1 vmnet8
```

(And yes, as you can see from the NICs, I also run VMWare Fusion 3.1.1, but the issue started upon upgrading to PD6)

```
$ ifconfig
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
 inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
 inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
 inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
 inet6 fd18:d7ce:18ee:1e60:223:32ff:fea0:fade prefixlen 128
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 ether HH:II:DD:DD:EE:NN
 media: autoselect
 status: inactive
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 ether HH:II:DD:DD:EE:NN
 inet6 HH:II:DD:DD:EE:NN%en1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x5
 inet 192.168.0.198 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
 media: <unknown subtype>
 status: active
fw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 4078
 lladdr 90:84:0d:ff:fe:ba:6d:2a
 media: autoselect <full-duplex>
 status: inactive
vnic0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 ether 00:1c:42:00:00:08
 inet 10.211.55.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.211.55.255
 inet6 fe80::21c:42ff:fe00:8%vnic0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x7
 inet6 ::1 prefixlen 64
 media: autoselect
 status: active
vnic1: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 ether 00:1c:42:00:00:09
 inet 10.37.129.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 10.37.129.255
 inet6 fe80::21c:42ff:fe00:9%vnic1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x8
 inet6 ::1 prefixlen 64
 media: autoselect
 status: active
vmnet1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 ether 00:50:56:c0:00:01
 inet 172.16.155.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.16.155.255
vmnet8: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
 ether 00:50:56:c0:00:08
 inet 192.168.102.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.102.255

$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 208.67.220.220
nameserver 208.67.222.222
```

Comment: Can you post the output of your ifconfig and the output of: cat /etc/resolv.conf (in Terminal.App of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by making some tests in your Terminal:

1. Use nslookup and try to lookup certain stuff (www.google.com, www.ibm.com, etc) See how it works from there.
2. Use ‘dig’ (another command) to do the same. Dig will be much more verbose and will show you more information about the Lookup per se.
3. Make sure your DNSs are correct in /etc/resolv.conf (try google’s 8.8.8.8 if unsure).
4. Check your Console for possible messages related to Network adapters or loops going on.

Edit: It all seems “normal”. Do you use Shared networking? Can you try disabling vnic0 and vnic1 (those are the parallels ones). I recall having slowness problems (back in parallels 3.x) which I fixed by using Bridged Networking instead of shared. I didn’t think the issue was still an issue a few years later!

Comment: 1 and 2) It sometimes resolves immediately, other times sucks as hell. That is what's so baffling. I actually ran "time nslookup" and "time dig" commands and I get weird behavior.

3) My DNS servers are definitely correct. I use OpenDNS because I want Google to at least not know all my porn habits.

4) I do see some weird kernel.log messages with VMWare info... (vmnet: VMNET_SO_BINDTOHUB: port: paddr vmnet: bridge-en1: media 80 dev 0x89f2404 family 2vmnet: Invalidating peer info for hub: 0, port: 0vmnet: VNetUserIfFree: freeing userIf at 0x9e8df00.) I'll have to look into this more. Thanks!

Comment: I too, use OpenDNS so try to disable all the virtual adapters provided by both Parallels and VMWare and start one by one. Bridged networking usually works best (for me) as it creates a “real” adapter (virtual anyway) and doesn’t mess with the creation of a “private network” between your Mac and your VMs.